# If a sequence of random variables {Sn} and an independent X both follow Bernoulli(1/2), why doesn’t the sequence converge to X almost surely?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, statistics

I know the sequence doesn’t converge to X in probability since P(|Sn-X|>=ε)=1/2 for some ε>0 as n->∞.

Almost sure Convergence is stronger than Convergence in probability, so almost sure convergence should not hold for this example.

But if I directly check the definition of almost sure Convergence,it seems to meet the condition. For all ω, Sn and X both output the same value hence they are equal. Wouldn’t the event have probability of 1?

I know I made mistakes somewhere, but I cannot figure it out. Thank you so much for any advice.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: "For all $ω$, $S_n$ and $X$ both output the same value" does not look correct to me.  They are independent so only have the same value for "half" the $\omega$.

Comment: @Henry hi Henry thank you for your comment! I guess I know where I made mistakes. The sample space Ω in the context would be S1 x S2, with Si being {0,1}, so only half of the ω from Ω are the ones for which Sn=X  i.e.{{0,0}, {1,1}}. In that sense, P(lim n-> ∞  Sn=X)=1/2, so almost sure convergence doesn’t hold. Is my understanding correct? Thank you

Comment: You're on the right track.  There's a technical point though: you can say $\mathbb{P}(S_n = X) = \frac{1}{2}$ for any fixed $n$, but you shouldn't expect $\lim_n S_n$ to exist if the $S_n$'s are all independent coin flips.  They're gonna oscillate between 0 and 1 infinitely often, not stabilize eventually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're confused about what it means to agree on $\omega$.  That's not the same thing as saying that the variables have the same probability distribution.  You could correctly say that $S_n$ converges *in distribution* or *in law* to $X$ (trivially - they all have the same distribution), but agreement in $\omega$ would be a strong form of pointwise convergence, which doesn't happen here.  This would only happen if the variables were identically the same (not independent).  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) for the types of convergence, where convergence in distribution is noted as being weaker than the types of convergence you named.

I'm gonna write $Y$ instead of $S_n$, but the logic below applies to $X$ and $S_n$ for any fixed $n$ you'd like.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Bernoulli(1/2) random variables.  Because they're *independent*, it's not true that $X$ and $Y$ always give the same result (that's what it means to be equal for all $\omega$).  Instead, we can model $X$ and $Y$ as projections onto each coordinate in the following product space:

[image: sample space for two independent variables]

Here $\Omega = \{0, 1\} \times \{0, 1\} = \{\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3, \omega_4\}$, with $\mathbb{P}(\omega_i) = \frac{1}{4}$.

You can confirm using these four points that: $\mathbb{P}(X = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X = 1) = \mathbb{P}(Y = 0) = \mathbb{P}(Y = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$.  So the variables share the same (marginal) distribution.  But their joint distribution (their relationship with each other) is determined by independence.  As you note in your comment, $X$ and $Y$ don't agree for all $\omega$.  They agree only at $\omega_1$ and $\omega_4$.  This explains why $\mathbb{P}(|S_n - X|\ge \varepsilon) = \frac{1}{2}$ and Henry's "half" comment.

If you really wanted to model your situation, you could pick a binary number uniformly at random between 0 and 2: $b_0.b_1 b_2 b_3 ...$  Then let $X = b_0$, $S_n = b_n$.  The independence of these variables suggests that any two of them should agree only half the time.  This also gives a way of seeing that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n$ almost surely does not exist - the sequence oscillates infinitely many times between 0 and 1 with probability 1.  In other words, there's no reason to expect that eventually the $S_n$'s all start agreeing with each other.  They're independent too (at least, I assume that was your intention).

Comment: @ Josh Keneda      Hi josh, thank you for your detailed explanation! One follow-up question, normally when we talk about Pointwise converge for a sequence of functions {fn} and f(not on probability space,from R to R), we say it holds if fn(x)=f(x) for all x from R. Is it true to say that fn and f are “dependent’’ in some sense since we plug in same real number on both sides? Thank you!

Comment: By the way, I think I can talk about the limit of Sn if the sequence is actually dependent? It still though doesn’t almost surely converge to X that is independent of the sequence.

Comment: I suppose you could say that the $f_n$ are dependent (i.e. not independent) with $f$ in that case.  If a sequence of independent variables converges almost surely, then they have to converge to a non-random constant (they can’t converge to an interesting random variable).  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978363/almost-sure-convergence-of-independent-random-variables-and-limit-is-constant).    So if $S_n \rightarrow X$ a.s. and $X$ is non-constant (i.e. random in any way), then there must be some ‘dependence’ between these variables.

Comment: About your last comment: you *might* have an interesting limit for $(S_n)$ if they’re not independent, but even total dependence doesn’t guarantee convergence.  For example, $S_1$ could *determine* the rest of the $S_n$’s and still $(S_n)$ might not converge.  Just let $S_n = S_1$ for all odd $n$ and $S_n = 1 - S_1$ (i.e. the opposite of what happened at $S_1$) for all even $n$.  Then the sequence $(S_n)$ constantly alternates (doesn’t converge).  So note that neither independence nor complete dependence necessarily imply convergence.  But convergence to a non-constant implies some dependence.

Comment: If I hand you a sequence of random variables and then say they’re “independent,” then I’ve fully determined their joint distribution.  There’s only one way to be independent: each variable just does its own thing, and information about one variable doesn’t affect any of the other variables.  But if I say that the sequence is “dependent,” that doesn’t give you enough information to decide their joint distribution, convergence, etc.  Hopefully the example in my last comment convinces you that there are a bajillion different ways for a sequence to be “dependent.”  Independence is special.